# How to make a button function as both open and close?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hamburger-menu

I want to apply a close state to the same hamburger button with an open state already applied. Close state is already applied to another button at a different location.. but I don't want to change that. I just want to duplicate the close state on the open button

```js
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {  
    $('.menu').click(function () {
    $('#css-menu').css({right:'0'});
});
    $('.close-menu').click(function() {
    $('#css-menu').css({right:'-340px'});
});
 });
</script>
```

```html
<li class='menu' title='Menu'></li>
```

Would appreciate if any help

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have a look at `toggleClass` - http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: Try `this.toggleClass()` to reference the element being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are being slightly unclear but I think you mean you want to use JQuery's toggleClass, or, I would use a click record, and check whether the count is even or odd: open or closed.

```
$(function() {  
    var clickCount = 0;
    $('.menu').click(function () {
        if(clickCount%2==0){
              //do when open
               $('#css-menu').css({right:'0'});
        }else{
             //do when closed
             $('#css-menu').css({right:'-340px'});
         }
        clickCount++;
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Same comment as above ^^^ Properties `left` and `right` trigger rebuild of layout in a critical rendering path of the browser.
https://csstriggers.com/left

Comment: This got the job done.. but I had to add  $('.close-menu').click(function() {
    $('#css-menu').css({right:'-340px'});
});
}); to keep the former responsive

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for toggleClass. Clicking on the specific `<li>` will toggle the state of that `<li>` only.

Use `this.toggleClass()` to reference the element being clicked.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.menu').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
li ul {
  display: none;
}
li.open ul {
  display: block;
}
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="menu">Menu 1
    <ul>
      <li>Sub item 1.1</li>
      <li>Sub item 1.2</li>
      <li>Sub item 1.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu">Menu 2
    <ul>
      <li>Sub item 2.1</li>
      <li>Sub item 2.2</li>
      <li>Sub item 2.3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to register new variable and count clicks.
Just add/remove nonexistent class "clicked" and test on click
if element "is" clicked

```js
$(function() {  
  $('.menu').click(function () {
    if ($(this).is('.clicked')) {
      $(this).css({left:0})
                    .removeClass('clicked');
    } else {
      $(this).css({left:20})
                    .addClass('clicked');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class='menu' title='Menu' style='position:relative'>AA</li>
```

Comment: By setting `left` like this you are triggering rebuild of layout in a critical rendering path of the browser, this is a potential perf issue. Be careful with this!

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 classes where one is your shown state the other is hidden state
Define the CSS for your classes

```css
#css-menu.hidden {
  right: -340px;
}
#css-menu.shown {
  right: 0;
}
```

Assuming class shown  = shown.
And class hidden=hidden

Add the shown(default) class your element
Class= 'hidden'

```
Then your script



  $('.menu').click(function(){
    $('#css-menu').toggleClass('shown hidden');
    });
```